# How to send email from SQL Server to gmail

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am a beginner in SQL and ASP.NET, basically i'm creating a website in that there is a contact us page. In that there are four textbox (Name, Email Address,Subject & Your Message). What ever i type in the text box it stored in the table's database in SQL. So now how to send the data (which is present in table) to gmail account.

Comment: Sending an email to Gmail is no different to sending an email to any other mail provider; use [`sp_send_dbmail`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Where that email is delivered to (gmail, Outlook, Yahoo, a company hosted STMP server) doesn't matter. SQL Server will simply connect to the email account you have configured and then that mail server does the rest of the work.

Answer (score -1):

Prerequisites: SMTP server (Gmail, exchange, any other)

#### Options

- Send mail from c#
- Send mail in database (wouldn't recommend as SQL Server is expensive in licensing)

How to do it from c#:

```
using(var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
{
    EnableSsl = true,
})
{
    var credentials = new NetworkCredential("your-sender-account@gmail.com", "your-sender-passworder"); // Don't store you password in clear text
    var smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;

    var to = new MailAddress("to-email@gmail.com");
    var from = new MailAddress("from-email@gmail.com");
    var mailMessage = new MailMessage(from, to)
    {
        Subject = "Your subject",
        Body = "Your content"
    };

    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

If you use gmail as your smtp server, you would need to [allow less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) in your gmail settings, of the account used in the `NetworkCredintial`

Documentation [SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: If i use this c# code for example i use in "NetworkCredential("xyz@gmail.com,"pass"), var to=(xyz@gmail.com), var from=(abc@gmail.com)". And without any issue i receive an email but problem is in the email if i expand the details it is showing "From:xyz@gmail.com To:xyz@gmail.com" .Although i type abc@gmail.com in "var from"